# Save to MySQL from PHP Form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

My Database Structure looks like this;
[image]

and my code looks like this;

```
<?php 
    $email_sql = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'myremovalsquote');

    // Check connection
    if ($email_sql->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $email_sql->connect_error);
} else { echo 'connected'; }
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <article>
                    <h1>Get Your FREE Quotes Now!</h1>
                    <div class="post">
                        <form method="post" action="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/quote">
                            <ul id="quoteform">
                                <li class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <h2>Where are you moving from?</h2>
                                        <select name="frompc">
                                            <option value="ab">Aberdeen (AB)</option>
                                            <option value="al">St Albans (AL)</option>
                                        </select>

                                        <p>What type of property are you moving from?</p>
                                        <select name="fromtype">
                                            <option value="storage">Storage</option>
                                            <option value="bungalow">Bungalow</option>
                                            <option selected value="house">House</option>
                                            <option value="multistory">Multi-Story</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <h2>Move details</h2>
                                        <input type="text" name="movedate" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY">

                                        <p>Is this date flexible?
                                        <select name="flexible">
                                            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                                            <option value="no">No</option>
                                        </select></p>

                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <h2>Where are you moving to?</h2>
                                        <select name="topc">
                                            <option value="ab">Aberdeen (AB)</option>
                                            <option value="al">St Albans (AL)</option>
                                        </select>

                                        <select name="totype">
                                            <option value="storage">Storage</option>
                                            <option value="bungalow">Bungalow</option>
                                            <option selected value="house">House</option>
                                            <option value="multistory">Multi-Story</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <h2>Extra Services</h2>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="packaging" value="Packaging">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="packing" value="Packing">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="furniture" value="Dismantle &amp; Reassemble Furniture">
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <h2>Notes / Additions</h2>
                                        <textarea name="notes">Enter text here...</textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <h2>Your Details</h2>
                                        Full Name
                                        <input type="text" name="fullname" value="Joe Bloggs">
                                        Contact Number
                                        <input type="text" name="contactnumber">
                                        Email Address
                                        <input type="email" name="email">
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <input type="submit" name="submit" required="required" value="Get Quotes!" id="emailbutton">

                                        <?php
                                        //CREATE VARIBLES
                                        if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

                                            $submitdate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($oldDate));

                                            $frompostcode = $_POST["frompc"];
                                            $fromtype = $_POST["fromtype"];

                                            $movedate = $_POST["movedate"];
                                            $flexible = $_POST["flexible"];

                                            $topostcode = $_POST["topc"];
                                            $totype = $_POST["totype"];

                                            $packing = $_POST["packing"];
                                            $packaging = $_POST["packaging"];
                                            $furniture = $_POST["furniture"];

                                            $notes = $_POST["notes"];

                                            $name = $_POST["fullname"];
                                            $contactnumber = $_POST["contactnumber"];
                                            $email = $_POST["email"];

                                        }
                                        ?>

                                        <?php
                                        //IMPORT TO DATABASE
                                        if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {

                                            //CLEANSE VARIBLES
                                            date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
                                            $submitdate = date('d/m/y h:i a', time());



                                            //IMPORT
                                            $query = " INSERT INTO `quotes`
                                                ('id', 'date', 'fullname', 'email', 'contactnumber', 'movedate', 'flexible', 'fromtype', 'frompostcode', 'totype', 'topostcode', 'notes')

                                                VALUES

                                                (NULL, '".$submitdate."', '".$name."', '".$email."', '".$contactnumber."', '".$movedate."', '".$flexible."', '".$fromtype."', '".$frompostcode."', '".$totype."', '".$topostcode."', '".$notes."'); ";

                                            mysqli_query($query);

                                            echo 'Thankyou <br />';

                                            echo mysqli_error();

                                            echo $query;

                                            mysqli_close($email_sql);
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I cannot for the life of me get the form to save to the database, I am learning PHP/SQL and I cannot see where I am going wrong, I'm aware that I need to use mysqli in place of mysql.

Comment: do you have any error? But If you are learning there are lot of tutorial on the web you can follow.

Comment: I'm getting no errors at all, that's the problem. When I check the database nothing has been entered.

Comment: @BradHouston Use try catch block to get the error.

Comment: You're mixing quote types an awful lot in your query.

Comment: @BradHouston can you please echo the **$query**

Comment: `mysql_` functions dont work with `mysqli`. They are different drivers.

Comment: Okay it says no database selected? I have selected a database right at the beginning of the document.

Comment: @BradHouston: You're selecting the database with `mysqli_*` functions and then trying to run the query with `mysql_*` functions.  They're separate drivers and can't be used together.

Comment: Additionally `\`$submitdate\`` is using the wrong quotes..

Comment: So its not connecting fine but still doesn't enter into the database, if i print the query I get this.

INSERT INTO `quotes` ('id', 'date', 'fullname', 'email', 'contactnumber', 'movedate', 'flexible', 'fromtype', 'frompostcode', 'totype', 'topostcode', 'notes') VALUES (NULL, '03/11/15 04:02 pm', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '');

Comment: That's not how `mysqli_real_escape_string` works, look at the manual you need the connection link.

Comment: I was about to answer this question but there is a mess that I think is better to edit so others wouldn't have the same problem..edited..;)

Comment: There are several errors in your PHP code. Check your PHP error log, or enable the display of errors in your script with: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would use PDO. If you choose to use PDO, you need to make sure that the option is enabled in your `php.ini` file. Most default installs of PHP have PDO installed already, but it may not be enabled. Find the line:

```
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

And uncomment it. So you should now have:

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Then you can begin to fix this with PDO:

```
//Place this section at the beginning of your `.php` file.
//Connect to your DB
$config = array(
    'host' => 'localhost'
    'username' => 'root'
    'password' => 'root'
    'dbname' => 'myremovalsquote'
);
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$config['host'].';dbname='.$config['dbname'],$config['username'],$config['password']);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//Place the following after your line: 
//if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
$submitdate = date('d/m/y h:i a', time());
$frompostcode = htmlentities($frompostcode);
$fromtype = htmlentities($fromtype);
$movedate = htmlentities($movedate);
$flexible = htmlentities($flexible);
$topostcode = htmlentities($topostcode);
$totype = htmlentities($totype);
$packing = htmlentities($packing);
$packaging = htmlentities($packaging);
$furniture = htmlentities($furniture);
$notes = htmlentities($notes);
$name = htmlentities($name);
$contactnumber = htmlentities($contactnumber);
$email = htmlentities($email);

//Create your query
//You don't need to have the 'id' in your query because it's an auto increment field in your DB. You prepare the statement to avoid SQL injection
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO quotes 
(date, fullname, email, contactnumber, movedate, flexible, fromtype, frompostcode, totype, topostcode, notes)
VALUES
(:submitdate, :name, :email, :contactnumber, :movedate, :flexible, :fromtype, :frompostcode, :totype, :topostcode, :notes)");

//Bind the variables to the query and run
$query_params = array(
    ':submitdate' => $submitdate,
    ':name' => $name,
    ':email' => $email,
    ':contactnumber' => $contactnumber,
    ':movedate' => $movedate,
    ':flexible' => $flexible,
    ':fromtype' => $fromtype,
    ':frompostcode' => $frompostcode,
    ':totype' => $totype,
    ':topostcode' => $topostcode,
    ':notes' => $notes
);
$query->execute($query_params);

//Close connection
$db = null;
```

Comment: I don't really want to mess with PDO until I crack the basics of PHP.

Comment: I can understand that and though PDO could take some extra time to learn, to me the syntax seems cleaner. I never learned the `mysql_` or `mysqli_` ways. I started directly on PDO. So, obviously I'm biased.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of playing around and research I found the code to be correct, for some reason the final part of executing the query to the database failed by using;

```
mysqli_query($query);
```

or

```
mysql_query($query);
```

but worked fine when I used the following;

```
$connect->query($query);
```

Comment: You are open to SQL injections with your updated code. What happened to your real escaping? Prepared statements should be used first. If you cant use those for some reason use escaping. You shouldn't just pass user input to your query though.